# WPF: Updating Database (TwoWay) doesn´t work with Linq-Query

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq

I try to establish a two-way data binding between a database query and a ListView with a Slider inside. Unfortunately the updating back to the source doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
context = new JKTEntities();

var query = from auf in context.Aufträge
            join kd in context.Debitoren on auf.Kundennummer equals kd.Kundennummer
            join art in context.Artikel on auf.ArtNr equals art.ArtNr
            join typ in context.Typen on art.TypID equals typ.ID
            select new FertigungDaten {
                Auftrag = (Int32)auf.AB_Nr,
                AB_KdNr = (Int32)auf.Kundennummer,
                Kunde = kd.Firma,
                Kommission = auf.Komission,
                ArtNr = (Int32)auf.ArtNr,
                Liefertermin = (DateTime)auf.AB_Lieferdatum,
                A_GehäuseVorbereiten = (Int32)typ.A_GehäuseVorbereiten,
                F_GehäuseVorbereiten = (Int32)auf.F_GehäuseVorbereiten,
                A_Vorschleifen = (Int32)typ.A_Vorschleifen,
                F_Vorschleifen = (Int32)auf.F_Vorschleifen,
                A_Schweissen = (Int32)typ.A_Schweissen,
                F_Schweissen = (Int32)auf.F_Schweissen,
                A_Schleifen1 = (Int32)typ.A_Schleifen1,
                F_Schleifen1 = (Int32)auf.F_Schleifen1,
                A_Beschriften = (Int32)typ.A_Beschriften,
                F_Beschriften = (Int32)auf.F_Beschriften,
                A_Kleben = (Int32)typ.A_Kleben,
                F_Kleben = (Int32)auf.F_Kleben,
                A_Aushärten = (Int32)typ.A_Aushärten,
                F_Aushärten = (Int32)auf.F_Aushärten,
                A_Schleifen2 = (Int32)typ.A_Schleifen2,
                F_Schleifen2 = (Int32)auf.F_Schleifen2,
                A_Montieren = (Int32)typ.A_Montieren,
                F_Montieren = (Int32)auf.F_Montieren,
                A_Reinigen = (Int32)typ.A_Reinigen,
                F_Reinigen = (Int32)auf.F_Reinigen,
                A_Prüfen = (Int32)typ.A_Prüfen,
                F_Prüfen = (Int32)auf.F_Prüfen,
                A_Verpacken = (Int32)typ.A_Verpacken,
                F_Verpacken = (Int32)auf.F_Verpacken
            };

lvAufträge.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

My XAML:

```
<Slider x:Name="Reinigen" 
        Width="50" Height="10" 
        Maximum="100" 
        SmallChange="1" 
        Value="{Binding F_Reinigen, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=A_Reinigen, Converter={StaticResource ProgressForegroundConverter}}" 
        ValueChanged="Reinigen_ValueChanged">
```

With a button I call:

```
res1 = context.SaveChanges();
```

`res1` is always 0 - nothing is stored :-(

Comment: My XAML: <Slider x:Name="Reinigen" Maximum="100" BorderThickness="0" Width="50" Height="10" SmallChange="1" Value="{Binding F_Reinigen, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=A_Reinigen, Converter={StaticResource ProgressForegroundConverter}}" ValueChanged="Reinigen_ValueChanged">

Comment: If this is a method context.SaveChanges(); in view model then do you get any error in there ? Share this method if possible.

Comment: `FertigungDaten` is not a tracked entity, it's just a view model.

Comment: Seeing your "answer": you didn't grasp what I tried to say in my previous comment. **EF can't persist `FertigungDaten`**. It's not a mapped entity. You have to "paint" changes to `FertigungDaten` back to the entity classes `Auftrag`, `Debitor` etc. and then call SaveChanges. You *may* use the PropertyChanged event for this, but your description doesn't reveal who subscribes to it.

Comment: Sorry, I´m quite new in WPF :-( Would be great if you have some more hints how this "painting" could be done the best way... Thank´s a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I´ve changed the following way, but still can´t store Changes to the database :-(

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
    [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value)) return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}

public class FertigungDaten : ObservableObject
{ 
    ...
    private int f_Reinigen;
    public int F_Reinigen
    {
        get { return f_Reinigen; }
        set { SetProperty(ref f_Reinigen, value); }
    }
    ...

}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a modification of your question.